# How to create event id using winston logging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

we are rendering events from kafka bus and writing into file systems using winston logger , Now to enhance some functionality user want to search events from the file so for that particular reason i want to generate some id with each event that we are writing to log file. SO my question is , is it possible to generate some sort of id's using `winston` when we log to file.

winstonServer.js

```
var Consumer = {
    start: function() {
        var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
            level: null,
            transports: [
                new(winston.transports.Console)(),
                new(winston.transports.File)({
                    filename: './logs/dit/server.log',
                    maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 15, // 15MB
                    timestamp: false,
                    maxFiles: 10,
                    json: false,
                    formatter: function(options) {
                        return options.message;
                    }
                })
            ]
        });

        function startConsumer(consumer) {
            consumer.on('message', function(message) {
                logger.log('info', message.value);
                io.io().emit('ditConsumer', message.value);
            });
            consumer.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('error', err);
            });
        };
        startConsumer(consumer);
    }
}
```

server.log

```
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took 43fd41a7-d1fb-4c19-9de6-19170aee171f a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can generate UUID (`npm install node-uuid --save`):

```
 const uuid = require('node-uuid');
```

, and then we have 2 solutions:

1. add it to log message via string interpolation :

   ```
   ...
    function startConsumer(consumer) {
       consumer.on('message', function(message) {
           logger.log('info', `[ID:${uuid.v4()}]${message.value}`);
           io.io().emit('ditConsumer', message.val);
       });
       consumer.on('error', function(err) {
           console.log('error', err);
       });
   };
   startConsumer(consumer);
   ```

   ...
2. add it to log message via meta - this allows uniformity between both transports :

   ```
      var Consumer = {
        start: function() {
        const formatter = function(options) {
                   return `[ID:${options.meta.ID}]${options.value || options.meta.value}`;
               };
        var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
         level: null,
         transports: [
             new(winston.transports.Console)({formatter}),
             new(winston.transports.File)({
               filename: './logs/dit/server.log',
               maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 15, // 15MB
               timestamp: false,
               maxFiles: 10,
               json: false,
               formatter
           })
       ]
   });

   function startConsumer(consumer) {
       consumer.on('message', function(message) {
           logger.log('info', message.value, {ID:uuid.v4(), value:message:value});
           io.io().emit('ditConsumer', message.value );
       });
       consumer.on('error', function(err) {
           console.log('error', err);
       });
     };
    startConsumer(consumer);
     } }
   ```

Comment: It is generating same id for all the logs and second issue is i see id is printing from `logger.log` in console but its not writing ids to `server.log` file

Comment: Yeop, i will correct once will arrive home - it should be logId: uuid.v4() right in the method call parameter . I'll check transport api and will correct it to state where it logs to file.

Comment: Yeah now i see new ids , but its still not writing ids to log file that was the whole purpose to haev ids in the log file so we can search it

Comment: I'll correct my post once i will be at home with all updates including file thing. Can you please add file structure to the file? Simple solution is to concatenate it to message .

Comment: i have added file content to question.

Comment: so i have to use one of the choice from your answer and what is $ represent in your code i am not familiar with ES6.Can

Comment: i fixed $ sign issue never mind, with first solution again id's are being generated same for every event

Comment: second solution its not writing value to file but i see id's are unique. can you please fix second choice so it can write options.value with Id

Comment: `[ID:84eeff59-5788-45b8-a253-d8750284bf0f]undefined
`

Comment: I've modified the answers - both.

Comment: The thing that probably you get message.value as undefined. - The problem might be not in 2nd solution, but in that fact you recieve message.value as undefined. It should work as previous version, for sure. Also 1st solution should generate unique ones too.

Comment: Check please if there problem in some other part of your code - according to what you wrote simply you have no message.value in your consumer 'message' event handler